Segmentation core dumped when trying to build a single linklist
I was learning link list concepts in C, as I was building a project that can create a single reverse order list, I am encountering segmentation code dumped again and again. Kindly help me find my errors

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int num;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node* createll(node *head, node *error);
void print_list(node *head);

int main(void){
    node *head = NULL;
    node *error = NULL;
    error->num = 1;
    error->next = NULL;

    head = createll(head, error);
    print_list(head);
    return 0;
}

node* createll(node *head, node *error){
    int len;
    printf("Size of list: ");
    scanf("%d", &len);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new_node == NULL) {
            return error;
        }
        printf("Enter the data: ");
        scanf("%d", &new_node->num);
        new_node->next = NULL;

        new_node = head;
        head = new_node;
    }

    return head;
}


void print_list(node *head){
    node *temp;
    printf("Data stored is : ");
    for (temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next){
        printf("%d-->", temp->num);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

this is my code. I

node *error = NULL;, error->num = 1; - what do you expect to happen here?

Whenever playing with linked lists, make sure you have a piece of paper and some crayons handy, then trace through every function in your code to make sure nothing gets disconnected or lost. The “segmentation fault” means that one of your nexts is pointing somewhere it shouldn’t (which we call a “dangling pointer”).

@Oka I just wanted to implement the notion of returning 1 as a practice if something goes wrong. So as i was following few tutorials, they said it is better when initializing a node assign it to NULL value at first then reassign it with different values

Here are some of the issues:

error = NULL followed by error->num = 1 is problematic. You should only dereference a pointer when you have allocated memory for it. As you have code to create a node elsewhere, you should not have this code here at all.

When you do new_node = head; you lose the reference to the node you had just created with malloc. So here you have a memory leak, and the loss of the number that the user had input. The following two points address this user input. Anyhow new_node = head is wrong. You could prefix the new node into the linked list by setting new_node->next = head, but this should better be done in a dedicated node-creating function.

Don't mix user-input logic with linked list logic. Keep the code for getting the user's input separated from the details of the linked list building logic. So I would perform all user-input logic in main, where you will not have code that de-references nodes, but where you only call the linked-list related function to do the job. This also means that the loop -- for entering the numbers of the list -- should not be placed inside a function that is concerned with linked list building details.

Related to the previous point, you should not have scanf("%d", &new_node->num). Although this works, it mixes input concerns with node implementation details. Instead, read the input into a plain int variable, and only create the corresponding node after that input has been made, inside a dedicated function that takes an int as argument.

Following the previous points, you should not have a createll function, but a create_node function, which is only concerned with allocating the memory, and initialising the two members of the created node.

error is a name that suggests it is some error-related item, but it is a node. The name seems not well-chosen.

When malloc returns NULL, then don't return from the function. There is no use in trying to continue the linked list building algorithm when you encounter such an error. Instead, output an error message and exit the program.

I would use Node as name for the type, with an initial capital. This is a matter of opinion though.


Here is a possible version of your code that addresses the above points:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int num;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node* create_node(int num, Node* next);
void print_list(Node *head);

int main(void) {
    Node *head = NULL;
    int num, len;

    // Perform input outside of functions that implement
    //    linked list operations (separation of concern).
    printf("Size of list: ");
    scanf("%d", &len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // Get the data into an int; not directly into a node member.
        printf("Enter the data for node %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &num);
        head = create_node(num, head);
    }
    print_list(head);
    return 0;
}

// Separate the logic for creating one node and 
//     for building a multi-node linked list:
Node* create_node(int num, Node* next) {
    Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (!new_node) {
        // Don't return, but exit
        printf("Could not allocate memory for a new node.");
        exit(1);
    }
    new_node->num = num;
    new_node->next = next;
    return new_node;
}

void print_list(Node *head){
    printf("Linked list: ");
    for (Node *temp = head; temp; temp = temp->next) {
        printf("%d -> ", temp->num);
    }
    printf("null\n");
}

Note that prepending values into a linked list produces a linked list that has its values in reversed order. From your question I understand that this is what you wanted to happen.

Thank you so much. You code was so simple to read and I just couldn't find a way at the time of coding that script to break out of a function, I just realized you could exit.

Look at these two lines as pointed out in a comment:
node *error = NULL;
error->num = 1;

Because *error is NULL you are writing at address 0x0 which causes the segmentation fault.  In other words: You just use a pointer without allocating any memory.
One possibility is to not use a pointer but just one instance of node.  In that case the memory is allocated on the stack:
node error;

error.num = 1;
error.next = NULL;

createll(head, &error);

Since createll() expects a pointer to the error parameter, you have to pass the address of the variable with &.
Alternatively you can allocate the memory on the heap with malloc():
node *error = malloc(sizeof node);
if (!error) {
    fprintf(stderr, "virtual memory exhausted!\n");
    exit(1);
}
error->num = 1;
error->next = NULL;

createll(head, error);

The second approach is probably better because if at one point you want to free() the memory that you have allocated, it is a recipe for trouble to mix stack and heap allocation.  You will have to detect whether the memory was allocated with malloc() because something like free(&error) will cause a runtime error.
You should also overthink your error handling. In general, failures of malloc() are not handled.  You just bail out with an error message.  Memory exhaustion is not considered a runtime problem but a configuration error.

This expands on the comment about the OP's problem. Are you not curious, as I am, about why the OP creates a node in main() to begin with? If the allocation in createll() fails, the value of head is lost. error is a very unusual name for a pointer...

Yes, it expands the comment, as I have mentioned in line 1 of my answer. And I have also commented on the "error handling" without giving a complete solution to the OP's homework. So what is the issue?

The issue is (imo) that the OP is quite obviously a beginner. This answer replicates myriad examples of what is already shown in countless other existing answers (nothing new here) while failing to enquire-about or address the beginner's demonstrated fundamental misunderstanding about how to properly reach their objective.

The answer replicates myriad examples because the question replicates myriad problems of beginners with pointers. Explaining how to properly reach their objective is out of scope because their objective is to finish their homework in time. Stackoverflow is not meant to assist in that.

"The answer replicates myriad examples because the question replicates myriad problems of beginners with pointers. ... Stackoverflow is not meant to" be clogged up with low-value questions, either. The OP's post currently has 0 DVs and 0 VTCs... This answer serves only to compound an already bad situation in the repository. Do you sanction the OP's use of error (whatever that is meant to achieve)? Suggesting how to use stack correctly, then writing, "but don't do that" is contradictory.

The bottom line is, do you feel that this is a high-quality and worthy answer?

Yes, I do. Because it precisely answers the question which was about a segmentation fault. Had they asked for a lecture, the answer would have been different.

There are, currently, 18,135 possible Q&A's in the repository found by searching [c] "segmentation fault"... I'm done here.

... almost done. Let's say the OP uses your idea to malloc() in main()... It could be done, if one is experienced and keeps track of things. Posit, though: user desires and enters only 1 node. Now, is the return from createll() the user's data, or is it error coming back because of a bad allocation. This answer does not help a beginner to understand that they've embarked on a treacherous path that is likely beyond their competence (being a beginner). But it does illustrate how to use stack correctly, then advises "don't do that"... Not what I'd consider "useful". That's why I've DV'd.

OP: "Kindly help me find my errors" Take note of the plural...

Please don't get me wrong. Taken as fragments, I concur with a number of the statements contained in this answer. However, as a whole, I find this answer to be lacking. BTW: if this (or any other question) emits the aroma of "homework", the SO FAQ page links to this. Interesting reading over there.

@GuidoFlohr Thank you for addressing the segmentation error. I am still a beginner at this, the notion of memory does excite me but in the same time it feels trying eat a big hamburger in one go.
